Upgrading mariaDB from 10.3 to 10.11 InnoDB error
I tried updating my MariaDB server from 10.3 to 10.11.7 on my CentOS Stream virtual machine.
I used the following statements:
curl -LsS https://r.mariadb.com/downloads/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash -s -- --mariadb-server-version="mariadb-10.11"
sudo yum update mariadb-server
sudo systemctl restart mariadb

And this is giving me the following errors using systemctl status mariadb.service:
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: No valid checkpoint was found; the log was created with MariaDB 10.3.28.
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [ERROR] Aborting
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.11.7 database server.

Using journalctl -xe i am getting the following output:
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Obtaining redo log encryption key version 1 failed (4294967295). Maybe the key or the required encryption key management plugin was not found.
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Reading checkpoint encryption info failed.
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Obtaining redo log encryption key version 1 failed (4294967295). Maybe the key or the required encryption key management plugin was not found.
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Reading checkpoint encryption info failed.
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: No valid checkpoint was found; the log was created with MariaDB 10.3.28.
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
May 13 10:32:34 Dev-DB mariadbd[1158171]: 2024-05-13 10:32:34 0 [ERROR] Aborting

I've tried the solutions from this thread Getting error "Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed" when starting MySQL:
So far i've tried:

renaming/moving the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files
innodb_force_recovery = 1

Both of these options didn't solve my issue.
How do I solve this issue?

It sounds like you might need to restore your databases from the backup, which you undoubtedly have taken prior to the upgrade. You would want to reinstall v10.3 for that, then follow the documented upgrade procedure.

Is there any type of encryption going on?

Thanks for your answers, I managed to solve it by downgrading again and restarting the process. I expect the clean shutdown step was skipped by me originally.

MariaDB must be cleanly shutdown before an upgrade. Start 10.3 gain on the datadir and ensure that the shutdown cleanly completes.
The error isn't:
Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed" when starting MySQL"

This can apply to any innodb error from permission denied on the OP linked question to something more internal like what would have been evident in earlier error messages. As such any advice there was totally wrong for the problem encountered.
Per official documentation, redo logs - the iblogfile[01] are not to be moved/removed/edited. Later versions of MariaDB won't let you start without them.
So:

put them back
start on MariaDB-10.3
cleanly shutdown on 10.3
then perform the upgrade.


I think this was my issue. I am unsure whether i did a clean shutdown originally and thus everything broke down. Reinstalled everything with my backup and managed to get it working now! Thanks alot !
